# Scraping webelements if found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently working doing a webscrape which in my case if sydsvenskan but will be a template over time for other sites.

I have currently done:

```
from typing import Optional

import attr
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from loguru import logger
from requests import RequestException
from requests.exceptions import (
    ConnectionError,
    ConnectTimeout,
    ProxyError,
    ReadTimeout,
    ChunkedEncodingError,
    SSLError,
    Timeout
)


@attr.dataclass
class Data:
    store: str = attr.ib(factory=str)
    name: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
    info: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
    image: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)


class Info:
    def from_page(url: str) -> Data:
        while True:
            try:
                with requests.get(url) as response:
                    if response.status_code == 404:
                        return Data(store="Sydsvenskan")
                    if response.ok:
                        doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
                    else:
                        response.raise_for_status()

                name = doc.select_one('span.prose-title')
                info = doc.select_one('div.article__preamble-wrapper')
                image = doc.select_one('img.article-image')

                return Data(
                    store="Sydsvenskan",
                    name=name.text.strip() if name else '',
                    info=info.text.strip() if info else '',
                    image=image['src'] if image else '',
                )
            except (
                    ReadTimeout,
                    Timeout,
                    ConnectTimeout,
                    ConnectionError,
                    ChunkedEncodingError,
                    SSLError,
                    ProxyError
            ) as err:
                logger.info(f"{type(err).__name__} at line {err.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}: {err}")
                continue

            except RequestException as err:
                logger.exception(f"{type(err).__name__} at line {err.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__},: {err}")
                raise RequestException from err

            except Exception as err:
                logger.exception(f"{type(err).__name__} at line {err.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__},: {err}")
                raise Exception from err


def main():
    info = Info.from_page(
        url="https://www.sydsvenskan.se/2021-07-14/flera-anhallna-for-senaste-tidens-skjutningar-i-malmo")
    if info is None:
        logger.info('No new payload')
    else:
        logger.info(f'New payload: {info}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The current "template" I have created is meant to be able to add more news sites in the future and to be able to use this as a template. We do know that each site is different so we will never have any similar but the template should make it easy to adept in the future.

I wonder if there is anything I can improve from here? I am mostly "worried" about the return of Data where I use the if else statement inside the dataclass, not sure if that is a correct way to do it?

Comment: Hi @Reinderien, Regarding the adopted stuff that you have taught me is still there. The reason I haven't added it here is due to I wanted to make it easy for the people to use the script where I am more curious about the scraping part where I use the dataclasses like you showed me before but without the dicts if you remember. The difference is that when we last spoke we or rather I didnt had the chance to ask if we find rhe webelement then we should return it with the dataclass and if not then return empty value and thats what I was looking for.

Comment: @Reinderien the context manager, the logging with discord notification and all that you have taught me is implemented but this was more a question regarding the "If we find a webelement, then we take the text/href or whatever else it can be and if we dont find the element then return empty."

Comment: @Reinderien I will work on a more real end to end scraper in that case :) Should I update this thread and create a new one for that?

Comment: @Reinderien I have now updated the code and this is the real code I have been working on for a while with some pause in between. I hope this is much better compare from the beginning :)

Comment: Does this scrape only a single page? Just 1?

Comment: @Mast Yes :) It should work in any sydsvenskan.se articles for now. :) Later on the point is to do a copy paste of this script and create for other sites such as bbc news etc etc...

Comment: For what Python version did you write this, Python 3.7? .8? .9?

Comment: @Mast Python 3.8 :) 3.8.2 to be exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `attrs` should not need to have every single property decorated; there's an automatic mode
- On 404 returning a mostly-useless data instance seems like a bad idea.
- Your first tuple of exceptions contains classes that are all derived from `RequestException`. Is there a need to spell every one of them out? Why not just catch `RequestException` itself?
- You have a polling loop that continually `get`s from the server with no delay. That's not a very nice thing to do to a website. Best to add a delay.
- Separating `Info` and `Data` is not helpful, and `Info` on its own contains nothing that deserves to be a class. Just make `from_page` a class method on `Data` itself.
- There is no need to check for `.ok`. `raise_for_status` will unwind the stack and obviate any other logic.

`Data` can look like:

```
@attrs(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True, slots=True)
class Data:
    store: str
    name: Optional[str] = None
    info: Optional[str] = None
    image: Optional[str] = None

    @classmethod
    def from_page(cls, url: str) -> 'Data':
        with requests.get(url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        name = doc.select_one('span.prose-title')
        info = doc.select_one('div.article__preamble-wrapper')
        image = doc.select_one('img.article-image')

        return cls(
            store="Sydsvenskan",
            name=name and name.text.strip(),
            info=info and info.text.strip(),
            image=image and image['src'],
        )
```

I suggest that your retry loop be in an outer method and not baked into `from_page`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the awesome answer! The reason of exception for requestException is that if I use a bad proxy or a slow proxy in the future, there is a high chance it would throw timeout or any of those given exception I posted. What I wanted to do is to retry again instead of raising it. - I have a question. What is the difference between doing `name=name.text.strip() if name else ''` compare to yours where you use `and`?

Comment: The `and` syntax defaults to `None` and short-circuits out the second half of the expression. IMO better that than an empty string, given that your member are marked `Optional`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!  I agree. Will do that right away too!

Answer (score 2):

[Reinderien's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/264107/200133) is good and covers most of the points I was going to raise, but there are still some things that seem odd to me.

Most contentiously, I'm skeptical that it makes sense for you to be using `attr`. This is not a library I'm previously familiar with, I had to track down [the documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) for it.

- It doesn't look like you're using any of the features attrs offers over [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html) (argument validation or sanitation; slotted classes).
- Both attrs and dataclasses have a `frozen` option which I feel pretty strongly *should* default to `True`.
- The API for attrs seems to be changing rather a lot from one version to the next. (They actually list this as an advantage, which is *ok*, but not an argument why you should use them.) In particular, you're using `attr.dataclass` ([which was never part of the official api?](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/408) I can't find any other documentation of it), and Reinderien is using `attrs`, which [is just an extra wrinkle for a new reader to work through](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/overview.html#on-the-attr-s-and-attr-ib-names).

Seconding some of Reinderien's points:

- Treat 404 as an error, not a dummy object.
- Don't poll too fast. If the first one fails, trying again too soon can make the problem *worse*; I suggest a 2-second delay. Also don't poll indefinitely; I would usually have the number of attempts be configurable and default to *two*.
- `Info` as a separate class is pointless.

Further points:

- The class name `Data` isn't great. `PageData` could be ok. If this is specific to sydsvenskan then call it `SydsvenskanData` or something.
- This is supposed to be a template system for various sites, right? What's the "template" part (that's the same across sites) and what's the sydsvenskan-specific part? Keep these clearly and cleanly separate from each other, so that the site-specific stuff can be swapped out seamlessly. Is that why you had a distinct `Info` class? If so, just have a top-level method, but make sure it's clearly associated with the site it's supposed to be used on.
- Reinderien implies that you should move your exception handling up out of your `Data`-builder function. Clearly you need two layers, with retry-logic  somewhere higher and the `Data(...)` call at the bottom. In keeping with my above point, all of the `requests` stuff should go in the higher layer with exception-handling and retry-logic; the `Data`-builder function should take a `BeautifulSoup` object as its argument.
- Will this mostly be used from the command line, or as a library? In both cases try to expose more of the options to the caller. For example, [the `argparse` library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html) takes some work to understand, but is well worth learning if you want to write CLI tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer aswell! Much much appreciated! Don't really know where to start honestly but I agree on everything. 1. Regarding the dataclass, I dont believe I can argue anything there as I have learned mostly from Reinderien and of course there is still improvents to do but good to know!

Comment: 2. Regarding the 404 and all other status you are also right, I should only handle the 200 and then the rest of the status code should be handled by a raise. Polling data was meant to be sleeping much longer than 2 seconds as I feel like I might ddos even thought they have good system probably but still. Good point!  I agree with the class name isn't great either as I do find PageData to be much better.

Comment: 3. Regarding the template, The specific part is meant that I scrape different values (webelements) for sydsvenskan compare to bbc news e.g. I guess thats the difference and who knows what other difference other sites has for difference than just webelements. Nothing I can say now already but maybe that gave you some more clearity?

Comment: 4. The exception handling, I assume you meant that I should do the exception inside the `main()` when calling `from_page` ? instead of having it inside the from_page function? If I understood you both right? and yes. Later on it will be a command line where Ic an use argparse to say which "site" i want to start monitoring. - Thats it for me :) Waiting for reply!

Comment: A lot of design decisions depend on _how_ the thing will be used. But one way or another it seems like you should have a function for making the requests and handling all the ways that can fail, and another function that builds a `Data` based on a `BeautifulSoup`. A function called `main` should be responsible for CLI usage of the script.

Comment: Agreed on all points. Use built-in dataclasses when possible. I have the misfortune of having to maintain a product on 3.6 that doesn't have them, so under some circumstances attrs are your only option.

Comment: Small question regarding the built-in dataclasses, do you referer to your example as you have provided with the @attrs before? or is it something I might missed?

Comment: As you mentioned regarding @attrs because of 3.6, how would it look like if you ran with higher than 3.6? Any examples? 

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you start with `from dataclasses import dataclass` instead of `from attr import attrs` (as in @Reinderien;s example), then `@dataclass(frozen=True)` will be a drop-in replacement for `@attrs(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)`, _for your purposes_. (You'll notice that I left out `slots`; dataclasses doesn't have any comparable option. The libraries are _very similar_, but not _the same_.

Comment: Thank you both! I wished I could split the bounty to give you each 50/50 :( You guys have been amazing!